# partitioningBy with a downstream collector produced an unexpected result

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream, collectors

I have a test program:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> a = Arrays.asList(1, 11);
        List<Integer> b = Arrays.asList(2, 22);
        List<Integer> c = Arrays.asList(3, 33);

        Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("a", a);
        map.put("b", b);
        map.put("c", c);

        Set<String> valid = new HashSet<>();
        valid.add("a");

        Map<Boolean, List<Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>>>> partitions =
            map.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(
                    entry -> valid.contains(entry.getKey())));

        System.out.println(partitions);

        // partition by the key of the map
        // then reduce the values into a single collection

        Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> result = map.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(
                entry -> valid.contains(entry.getKey()),
                Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,
                                   Collectors.reducing(new ArrayList<>(),
                                                       (l1, l2) -> {
                                                           l1.addAll(l2);
                                                           return l1;
                                                       }))));

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

I'm expecting the final result to be

```
{false=[b=[2, 22], c=[3, 33]], true=[a=[1, 11]]}
{false=[2, 22, 3, 33], true=[1, 11]}
```

But in the actual result, both true and false keys have all 6 integers:

```
{false=[b=[2, 22], c=[3, 33]], true=[a=[1, 11]]}
{false=[1, 11, 2, 22, 3, 33], true=[1, 11, 2, 22, 3, 33]}
```

Notice the 2 partitioning functions are exactly the same. But the downstream mixed up the values in the separate partitions. How can that be? I assume the downstream would only operate on each partition...

What did I miss here?

Thanks.

Comment: The equivalent of the first would have been `Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> result = map.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(
                        entry -> valid.contains(entry.getKey()),
                        Collectors.flatMapping(e -> e.getValue().stream(),
                                Collectors.toList())));`. The two partitioning predicates are same, there downstream are not.

Comment: @Naman, thanks for the comment. Your code probably works, but I'm using Java 8 which does not have flagMapping. Sorry, I forgot to tag javaj-8.

Comment: For reducing same ArrayList referrence is used, an easy fix is `List<Integer> l3 = new ArrayList<>();l3.addAll(l2);l3.addAll(l1);return l3;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reducing same ArrayList reference is used in both partition.
You can use `Collectors.toMap` and create a new instance merging two lists.

```
Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> result = 
        map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> valid.contains(e.getKey()), Map.Entry::getValue, 
        (l1, l2) -> {
          List<Integer> l3 = new ArrayList<>(l1);
          l3.addAll(l2);
          return l3;
        }));
```

And if you want to use the same taste

```
Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> result = 
        map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(e-> valid.contains(e.getKey()), Map.Entry::getValue,
            (l1, l2) -> Stream.concat(l1.stream(), l2.stream())
                              .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: Your answer works, so I'll accept it. But I prefer the recommendation in your comment above. The crux of the problem is the same identity object being shared across the partitions.

Comment: @James Actually you are modifying reducer identity value, that not supposed to do, that's why both partitions have same List instance. As suggested create new instance rather modifying.

Comment: Very true. Immutability is at the core of functional programming. Thanks.

Comment: That’s why you shouldn’t use Reduction for such a task but Mutable Reduction aka a collector, e.g. `Collectors.partitioningBy(entry -> valid.contains(entry.getKey()), Collectors.flatMapping(entry -> entry.getValue().stream(), Collectors.toList()))`

Answer (score 0):

To complete [*already accepted answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63498411/3764965), you can use [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) using your classifier with [`Collectors.flatMapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#flatMapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) as of Java 9 as a downstream collector.

```
Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> result = map.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
         e -> valid.contains(e.getKey()), 
         Collectors.flatMapping(e -> e.getValue().stream(), Collectors.toList())));
```